# Prove that if $A, B,C$ and $D$ are sets, then $(A ×B)∩(C ×D) = (A ∩C)×(B ∩D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Give an example of a disproof to show that if A, B,C and D are sets, 
then 
$$(A ×B)∩(C ×D)= (A ∩C)×(B ∩D)
$$

Comment: There are several counter examples that spring to mind right away.  What have you tried?

Comment: The proof below is a better answer than to what I was originally looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prove is like follow
\begin{align}
(x,y)\in(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)&\iff (x,y)\in(A\times B)\land (x,y)\in(C\times D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \land y\in B) \land (x\in C \land y\in D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \land x\in C) \land (y\in B \land y\in D)
\\
&\iff (x\in A \cap C) \land (y\in B \cap D)
\\
& \iff (x,y) \in (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)
\end{align}